# SpeechSynthesis random stops with talking when talking

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, speech-synthesis

SpeechSynthesis stops with talking in chrome extension but he can talk, but not so long

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(
    function() {
        chrome.contextMenus.create(
            {
                title: "Read",
                id: "read",
                contexts:["selection"]
            }
        );
    }
);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
    var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(info.selectionText);
    utterance.lang = "nl-BE";
    utterance.volume = 0.5;
    utterance.rate = 0.8;
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(
        function() {
            chrome.contextMenus.create(
                {
                    title: "Read",
                    id: "read",
                    contexts:["selection"]
                }
            );
        }
    );

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(onClickHandler);

    function onClickHandler(info, tab) {
        var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(info.selectionText);
        utterance.lang = "nl-BE";
        utterance.volume = 0.5;
        utterance.rate = 0.8;
        function myTimer() {
        speechSynthesis.pause();
        speechSynthesis.resume();
        var myTimeout = setTimeout(myTimer, 10000);
      }
        var myTimeout = setTimeout(myTimer, 10000);
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Stop Timer once whole sentence read out.

```
        utterance.onend = function (event) {
            clearTimeout(this.myTimeout);
        }
    };
```